# Generic BaseFragment architecture with bounded type parameters to work with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am trying to come up with an architecture for my BaseFragment. Here is what I've accomplished so far:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends BaseViewModel> extends Fragment {   

       private ViewModel viewModel;

       onAttach(Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context)
         viewModel = (T) ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity() , new BaseViewModel.Factory(getActivity())).get(getViewModelClass());
         // viewModel.registerView(getViewImpl());
       }
}
```

and when I am creating any new Fragment, I do like this:

```
public class SomeFragment extends BaseFragment<SomeViewModel> {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

}
```

Its all fine but what if I want to create a Frgament where in I don't need any ViewModel? Should I remove the bounded type arguments from the BaseFragment and register the ViewModels in their respective Fragment? If so then what is point having bounded type arguments in the BaseFragment, it's not granular enough.

Comment: why don't you pass the viewmodel as a parameter?
or make the viewmodel nullable? where it is OK to have a null viewmodel

Comment: "why don't you pass the viewmodel as a parameter?" - I am not sure if it'd be a good idea. See #4 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0.  Passing null and handling it in VM seems like an overkill

Comment: first of all, onAttached is deprecated
second, if you instantiate the viewmodel without knowing if you need one, it is a bad idea. you can pass in the fragment arguments bundle some info to indicate what to do to create/not create a viewmodel

Comment: I recommend not sharing fields like this between Fragments through inheritance. Duplication is cheaper than incorrect coupling.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yah, I realised it as my app grew. Having a BaseFragment with bounded type arguments felt like too much over engineering.

Comment: I've done that before, never again :D